# VB Return a single value from SQL

Tags: sql, vb.net

I am trying to retrieve a single integer value. There will always be one and only one record in the DB for this select. I want to connect, retrieve store and display this value. is this executescalar the way to go?

```
  Dim sqlquery As String
        Dim ConnectionString As String
        ConnectionString = "Server=" + ServerName + "\" + InstanceName + "; Database=" + DatabaseName + "; User Id=" + UserId + ";Password=" + Password + ";"
        sqlquery = "SELECT severity FROM from dbo.SettingsSub where SEB_SettingsID = 'Severity"

        'Connect
        Using conn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(ConnectionString)
            conn.Open()
            Using comm As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(sqlquery, conn)
                CurrentSeverity = Convert.ToInt32(comm.ExecuteScalar())
                txtCurrentSeverity.Text = CurrentSeverity
                conn.Close()
            End Using 'comm
```

Comment: Yes, do you have a problem? (Apart from the missing closing quote in the where clause)

Comment: Sometimes...... you just need a fresh pair of eyeballs

At least it blew up on the correct line now... with an additional 'FROM'

Comment: thats literally all I needed THANKS!

Comment: Why do you convert the scalar to an int32 in order to put it in a text-field? Why not just place the scalar in the text-field?

Answer (score 0):

"There will always be one and only one record in the DB for this select." 
Even though you know that this is the case you should always use a **"Select top 1"** statement in this scenario as you never know what will happen in the future.

Comment: Good catch, I added it in after posting and optimizing my sql selects.